# How to rename columns using a for loop starting with a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

This code successfully renames my columns by adding a string to the front of every column name:

```
df.columns = ["Starting Words: " + str(col) for col in df.columns]
```

However, I don't want to change the first two column names.  How do I start this `for` loop at the 3rd column?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. What did you try? How did it fail?

Comment: I only tried what I wrote.  Didn't know where to go from there, other than me knowing [2:] for location.  I'm not as experienced as you which is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a conditional expression:

- if it's the first or second column, the new name is equal to the old name
- otherwise, the new name is the old name with a prefix

Now you only need to get the column index while iterating. That's what the `enumerate` function is for.

```
df.columns = [
    str(col) if i < 2 else "Starting Words: " + str(col)
    for i, col in enumerate(df.columns)
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.columns = [f"{'Starting Words: ' if idx>1 else ''}{col}" 
              for idx, col in enumerate(df.columns)]
```

or

```
df.columns = list(df.columns[:2]) + [f"Starting Words: {col}" for col in df.columns[2:]]
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works also.  Your second option is what I was trying to figure out, as I knew about the [:2] and [2:], but didn't know how to put it into action.